# Selecting a dynamically added row in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to target the last created row and run the query to change one of the columns with data used from a database. Currently, once an input has been entered into the first column, the column (measure) is changed, however this only works for the first row and none of the dynamically added rows. 
[Entering first ingredient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EitF.png)

[Entering another ingredient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFb7A.png)

The jquery code that I am using:

```
$(function(){
$(".ingredients").on("change", ".auto_"+i, function(){
    var ingredient = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "update_ingredients.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            ingredient: ingredient
        },
        success: function(response){
            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            $('#measure_'+i)
                .find('option')
                .remove()
                .end()
                .append('<option value="' + data['GmWt_Desc1'] + '">' + data['GmWt_Desc1'] + '</option>')
                .val(data['GmWt_Desc1'])
                .append('<option value="' + data['GmWt_Desc2'] + '">' + data['GmWt_Desc2'] + '</option>')
                .val(data['GmWt_Desc2'])
            ;
        },
    });
});
```

});

Table row involved:

```
<tr>
        <tbody class="ingredients">
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Egg" name="ingredient[]" class="auto_0" required/></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="Integer Value" name="measureNo[]"  required/></td>
            <td><select id="measure_0"><option value="Select ingredient">Select an ingredient first!</option></select>
            <td><input type="button" id="add" value="Add" /></td>
        </tbody>
    </tr>
```

When applying changes to the first row, after adding more rows, the change occurs in the last row's columns. Is there a reason as to why the query does not run when making changes in any other rows?

Comment: Good God, what dish are you creating that calls for eggnog and polish sausage??

Comment: Haha just a random input. I'm also incrementing variable 'i' everytime a new row is added.

Comment: $(".ingredients").on("change", ".auto_"+i, function()  Pretty sure this is not going to do what you think it is.  It was a parameter passed as a string ".auto_0" into a function.  The string is not going to somehow become ".auto_1".  You need to delegate the handler without the filter, and add a data item somewhere within your structure that holds the value of i so you can retrieve it on the event handler.

Comment: So do you mean: $(".auto_"+i).on("change", function() instead?

Comment: I've changed it to the following: '$(".ingredients").on("change", function(){
  var ingredient = $('.auto_'+i).val();' and that seemed to do the job